# Mask/unmask password field programmatically?

Tags: android, string

I am currently working on android project, I want to allow the user to hide or show their password on the screen by selecting a checkbox.

How would I go about replacing every character in the string with * character or is there a particular way to do this.

For example if the password is `my_password` I want it to be replaced with `***********`.

Comment: Verify the title edits are indeed the question really being asked .. I believe it is a UI issue, not actually "replacing all characters in a string with a *".

Comment: Replacing characters in a string won't do what you want. You want to display a particular character (`*`) for each character the user enters, and you need to do it *as they're entered*.

Comment: @pst, you're right that is a better title, couldn't think of the word

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [setTransformationMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTransformationMethod%28android.text.method.TransformationMethod%29) on TextView along with [PasswordTransformationMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod.html) to display stars.